# Проблема с if и типом данных

Tags: javascript

Есть простейшее условие

```
dolya=parseFloat(document.getElementById("dolya").value);
tmp_zn1_dolya1=0;zn1_dolya1=parseFloat(tmp_zn1_dolya1);
if(dolya>0.83)    {zn1_dolya1=1;}
if(dolya>0.67)     {zn1_dolya1=0.84;}
if(dolya>0.5)  {zn1_dolya1=0.68;}
if(dolya>0.33)    {zn1_dolya1=0.56;}
if(dolya>0.17)    {zn1_dolya1=0.36;}
if(dolya<0.17)    {zn1_dolya1=0.2;}
alert(zn1_dolya1)
```

к примеру  есть `dolya=0.625` выдает `0.36`, хотя должно `0.68`
Как решить проблему?

Comment: Для IE>8 и других браузеров: `zn1_dolya1=[0.83,0.67,0.5,0.33,0.17,-1].reduce(function(p,v,i) {return p ? p : dolya>v ? [1,0.84,0.68,0.56,0.36,0.2][i] :0},0);`

Answer (score 1):

Используйте **else if**, чтобы тело каждого условия выполнилось только 1 раз. В вашем примере выполнятся все условия начиная с `dolya > 0.5` и заканчивая `dolya > 0.17`. Это значит, что выполнится тело каждого такого условия, а в zn1_dolya1 будет занесено значение последнего выполненного: `if(dolya>0.17) {zn1_dolya1=0.36;}`. Так же у вас нет проверки для случая с `dolya>0.17`. Предположу, что она нужна, тогда в конце достаточно написать **else**(Условие выполнится для всех случаев, когда `dolya <= 0.17`).

```
dolya=parseFloat(document.getElementById("dolya").value);
tmp_zn1_dolya1=0;zn1_dolya1=parseFloat(tmp_zn1_dolya1);
if(dolya>0.83) {zn1_dolya1=1;}
else if(dolya>0.67) {zn1_dolya1=0.84;}
else if(dolya>0.5) {zn1_dolya1=0.68;}
else if(dolya>0.33) {zn1_dolya1=0.56;}
else if(dolya>0.17) {zn1_dolya1=0.36;}
else {zn1_dolya1=0.2;}
alert(zn1_dolya1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `if/else if` можно также использовать конструкцию `switch`. Используется тот факт, что условия `case` в `switch` проверяются последовательно. Код выглядит немножко странно, но работает.

```
switch (true) {
    case (dolya > 0.83) :
        zn1_dolya1 = 1;
        break;
    case (dolya > 0.67) :
        zn1_dolya1 = 0.84;
        break;
    case (dolya > 0.5) :
        zn1_dolya1 = 0.68;
        break;
    case (dolya > 0.33) :
        zn1_dolya1 = 0.56;
        break;
    case (dolya > 0.17) :
        zn1_dolya1 = 0.36;
        break;
    default :
        zn1_dolya1 = 0.2;
}
```

Необходимо отметить, что условия должны идти в порядке убывания чисел.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы проверял условия на принадлежность к диапазону 
if(dolya>0.33 && dolya < 0.6) {zn1_dolya1=0.56;}
Но согласен с тем что писали выше, что elseif. Надо использовать а лучше switch